# Erroneous SciPy 1.7 source build

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, scipy, pythran

When installing SciPy 1.7.1 [from source](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/building/linux.html) on Linux using

```sh
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

(along with environment and `site.cfg` hacking as needed) I end up with a broken build. My particular build recipe works for SciPy <= 1.6

Once SciPy 1.7.1 is built, importing e.g. `scipy.optimize` or `scipy.special` results in errors

> AttributeError: module 'scipy.special._ufuncs_cxx' has no attribute '**pyx_capi**'

> ImportError: cannot import name 'levinson' from 'scipy.linalg._solve_toeplitz'

> ImportError: cannot import name 'csgraph_to_dense' from 'scipy.sparse.csgraph._tools'

What has changed, and how do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the `site-packages` directory I see that SciPy 1.7 installs itself as a zipped Python egg, whereas previous versions used to install as directories (though still Python eggs). This behaviour can be chosen by specifying the [`zip_safe`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/miscellaneous.html#setting-the-zip-safe-flag) argument to `setuptools.setup()`, called from within `setup.py`. In SciPy 1.7 this is [called as](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.7.1/setup.py)

```py
setup(**metadata)
```

with `metadata` not including `'zip_safe'`, meaning that whether zipped eggs are safe to use are automatically determined. This might also be the case for older SciPy versions, but for whatever reason the process ends up declaring zipped eggs to be safe for 1.7 on my system, which does not seem to be the case.

Manually adding

```py
metadata['zip_safe'] = False
```

above `setup(**metadata)` prior to executing `setup.py` results in the egg being a directory (as opposed to a zipped archive), and the build works.

To do the patching of `setup.py` programatically, use e.g. (GNU sed)

```sh
sed -i "s/\(^ *\)\(setup *(.*\)$/\1metadata['zip_safe'] = False; \2/" setup.py
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does a command like `git submodule update --init && git clean -xdf && python3.9 -m pip install --user --upgrade --use-feature=in-tree-build .` result in?